# how to implement widget switches?

Tags: android, switch-statement

I am looking for widget [Switch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html). Not switch statement or switch activity etc.

There was very rare tutorial on web.

My problem is graphical layout in xml cannot see the switch.

my xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="推送通知"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textOff="关"
        android:textOn="开" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The error occurs at the  there.

Error

`Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?`
`Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.`

`NOTE: This project contains resource errors, so aapt did not succeed, which can cause rendering failures. Fix resource problems first.`

`Failed to find style 'switchStyle' in current theme`
`java.lang.NullPointerException`
`Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log`

I got no idea how to do it?

Comment: If you just can't see the Switch, you might need a `layout_below` attribute on your `Switch` in order to position it below the second TextView. Though the `layout_alignParentRight` ought to make it visible if there's space, so we'll need a bit more information about what's wrong.

Comment: i had updated the error in graphical layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AndroidManifest.xml should have

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Because Switch widget supports 14 and above API level only..

A simple example for you..

```
main.xml
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/bluetooth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dip"
                android:text="Bluetooth"
                />

</GridLayout>

ur .java



package time.pass;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TimePass extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_pass );

    Switch s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.bluetooth);
    if (s != null) {
        s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }
}


@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is " + (isChecked ? "on" : "off"),
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: i am working with android:minSdkVersion="18         android:targetSdkVersion="19" but still same error, any suggestion?

Comment: Have you got the solution for same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score -3):

Use the theme of your xml file as `Theme.DeviceDefault`